# ASP.NET Core MVC Unique Phone Number and SSN

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am working with ASP.NET Core MVC Identity and I want to add a unique field for both Phone Number and SSN (National ID). Since I am working with .NET Identity I could not found a controller that is scaffolded after scaffolding .NET Identity.

As far as I know, there are two ways to solve this. One by doing a `remote-validator` and the other by implementing a function in the `Controller`. I would search inside the DB for existing Phone Numbers and SSN then if True return a JSON result showing an error message. But, how would I do this ? or are there any more efficient solutions ?

Folder Structure for Identity:

Register.cshtml custom fields snippets:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="National ID is a required field")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Nationa ID")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength =10, ErrorMessage ="National ID must be 10 digits")]
    [RegularExpression("(^[0-9]*)(^[12].*)", ErrorMessage = "National ID must be numeric")]
    //TODO: make it unique
    public string NationalId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Phone Number is a required field")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?:[+?0?0?966]+)(?:\s?\d{2})(?:\s?\d{7}))$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")] 
    //TODO: Make it unique
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Thanks

Comment: IIRC, you need to open the code behind for Register.cshtml. ASP.NET Core Identity started using the dreaded ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, so there's no Controller

Comment: Yeah I know it is under Register.cshtml in the file Register.cshtml.cs. But how would I approach such functionality for custom fields uniqueness

Comment: The easiest would be to use the POST event handler to do the second approach, I think it's `OnPost` but I haven't used Razor Pages, so you'd need to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using
`[Remote(action: "Action Name", controller: "Controller Name",AdditionalFields = "Your additional parameters of the action", ErrorMessage = "Message displayed in form after validation")]`
above the validating property.

*Please note that the value of the property will be used as the first parameter in you action.*

Then in the controller you point the attribute to add your action to get the json result from your database

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActionName(string phoneNumber)
    {
        // Do Database checking
        {
            // If value already exists
            return Json(false);
        }
        //If unique value
        return Json(true);
    }
```

finally you should include following scripts at your View or _Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

For a more detailed atricle please check
[this one here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/remote-validation-in-mvc-5-using-remote-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public DbSet<mdlApplicationUser> mdlApplicationUser { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<mdlApplicationUser>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.PhoneNumber)
            .IsUnique();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

in Manage/index.cshtml.cs:

```
if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
        {
            try
            {

                var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);

                if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    StatusMessage = "Unexpected error when trying to set phone number.";
                    return RedirectToPage();
                }
            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
    
                    string err=ex.InnerException.ToString();
                
                    if (err.IndexOf("duplicate key row in object 'dbunk.AspNetUsers' with unique index 'IX_AspNetUsers_PhoneNumber'.") > -1)//Checking part of the error that sql returns
                {
                    j = 1;
                
                }
                
            }
        }
        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        if(j==1)
        {
            StatusMessage = "Number " + Input.PhoneNumber + " Number 0 has been used by someone else";
        }
        else
        {
        StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
        }
```